# How do I use tab stops in enumerate or itemize?

Tags: lists, enumerate, tabbing

Current code is:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=LEVEL \arabic{*},leftmargin=*]
    \item Description of Level 1 \quad L1 \\ \emph{more text}
    \item Description of Level 2 \quad L2 \\ \emph{more text} 
\end{enumerate}
```

but the `\quad` does not align L1 and L2 uniformly vertically. I want to replace `\quad` with a tab but the `tabbing` environment does not allow mixing with an `enumerate`!

Comment: It might be easier to do this with a `tabular` environment instead of a list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the package `tabto`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}
  \TabPositions{4cm}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=LEVEL \arabic{*},leftmargin=*]
    \item Description of Level 1 \tab L1 \\ \emph{more text}
    \item Description of Level 2 \tab L2 \\ \emph{more text} 
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can also use more tabs

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}

\NumTabs{3}

\begin{itemize}
\item some text           \tab i want this              \tab same here
\item another text        \tab and this to be at the    \tab same here
\item not the same length \tab same level after let say \tab seconde level here
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You made my day with this last one, man

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boxes with equal widths to make a "tab". It is not the real thing but works quite well

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\tablen}
\newcommand\tabbox[2][\tablen]{\makebox[#1][l]{#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \settowidth\tablen{Description of Level 1 \quad}
    \item \tabbox{Description of Level 1} L1 \\ \emph{more text}
    \item \tabbox{Description of xxx}     L2 \\ \emph{more text}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```