# Making enumerate equations aligned

Tags: enumerate

I'm quite new to latex and need help making my equations in enumerate aligned by "b" for school project.

Right now it looks like:
[image]

But I need it to look like:
[image]

My code right now:
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please do not post code as images. We would appreciate a minimal compilable code example.

Comment: Do the answers to this question help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15628/134144
Alternatively, you could use a tabular or an aligned environment instead of the enumerate environment. Additionally, please do not post code as images, but rather put it directly into the question. Please as well extend the code snippet to be a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) .

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `listliketab` in the place of `enumerate:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listliketab}

\begin{document}

\storestyleof{enumerate}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum)}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\begin{listliketab}
  \begin{tabular}{L*{2}{>{$}l<{$}}}
    \tabitem & a = 5, & b = 3 \,; \\
    \tabitem & a = 4, & b = 6 \,; \\
    \tabitem & a =3{,}2, & b = 2{,}3 \,; \\
    \tabitem & a = 2\sqrt{5}, & b = 3\sqrt{5} \,; \\
    \tabitem & a = \sqrt{3}, & b = \sqrt{7} \,; \\
    \tabitem & a = 1, & b = √{0{,}1}.
  \end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution, based on a code by @Werner for [switching between left and right equation numbers within the same document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193535/switch-between-leqno-and-reqno-options-of-amsmath-in-the-same-document), and the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`. The `=` signs will be aligned in both columns:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}[2em]
\leqnomode
\begin{alignat}{2}
a &= 5, & b & = 3 \,; \\
a & = 4, & b & = 6 \,; \\
a & =3{,}2, & b & = 2{,}3 \, ; \\
a & = 2\sqrt{5}, &\qquad b & = 3\sqrt{5} \, ; \\
a & = \sqrt{3}, & b & = \sqrt{7} \, ; \\
a & = 1, & b & = \sqrt{0{,}1}.
\end{alignat}
\end{fleqn}

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= dx^2 + ex + f
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Out of the box, this does not compile. The error:`./ListLikeTab-ex.tex:20: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char √ (U+221A)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.` Using MacTeX 2017 updated this morning.

Comment: OOps! Sorry, it's a problem with my editor: it displays maths symbols (but saves as TeX code). I've fixed it. Please try the modified code.

Comment: I assumed something of the sort, so glad it's fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @bernard : where is available the listliketab package? Not found in ctan.org right now.

Comment: @pzorba75 Hmmm, strange, it is there indeed [listliketab package](https://ctan.org/pkg/listliketab).

Comment: @pzorba75: It is part of the MiKTeX and TeX Live distributions. Other than that, you'll find it in `https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib`, but it's better to  install it via your package manager.